# Rendering issue on ZF2, trying to render layout to get html code

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I've an issue with PhpRenderer, let's start by the context. I have to generate a bunch of static pages to cache them (with cache storage using file system adapter). So I wired an event on  EVENT_ROUTE to serve the static page if it exists, and an event on EVENT_FINISH to get the response content and write it to a cache file. It works just fine.

My problem is, I want to generate these pages before navigation (I've around 3 millions pages to generate). My idea was to create a controller I can call in CLI, to be able to schedule the huge task. So in my second controller, I call the one that return the ViewModel I'm interested in, build the renderer, and render my action ViewModel and my layout to get the whole HTML of my page.

Here is the code :

```
public static function GetStaticResponse(ServiceManager $sm, AbstractActionController $controller, array $routeParams){
    $event = new MvcEvent();
    $request = new Request();
    // $controller = new $controller();
    $router = $sm->get('Router');

    // Test values!!!
    // $routeMatch = new RouteMatch(array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'showad', 'ad_id' => '1002293747'));
    // Test values end !!

    $routeMatch = new RouteMatch($routeParams);

    $event->setRouter($router);
    $event->setRouteMatch($routeMatch);
    $controller->setEvent($event);
    $pluginManager = $sm->get('ControllerPluginManager');
    $controller->setServiceLocator($sm);
    $controller->setPluginManager($pluginManager);

    $view = $controller->dispatch($request);

    $config = $sm->get('Config');

    $renderer = new PhpRenderer($config);
    $map = new TemplateMapResolver(
        $config['view_manager']['template_map']
    );

    $renderer->setResolver($map);
    $renderer->setHelperPluginManager($sm->get('ViewHelperManager'));
    $view->setTemplate('showad');
    $content = $renderer->render($view);

    $renderer = new PhpRenderer($config);
    $map = new TemplateMapResolver(
        $config['view_manager']['template_map']
    );
    $renderer->setResolver($map);
    $renderer->setHelperPluginManager($sm->get('ViewHelperManager'));
    $viewLayout = new ViewModel();
    $viewLayout->setTemplate('layout/layout');
    $viewLayout->setVariables(array("content" => $content));

    $render = $renderer->render($viewLayout);
    unset($event, $request, $router, $routeMatch, $controller, $pluginManager, $view, $config, $renderer, $content, $viewLayout);
    return $render;

}
```

this method works fine when I only execute it once. When I call this method again in a loop, the Renderer seems to have some static properties and whenever the layout calls helpers like 'headTitle' or 'headLink', the title and link are append again and again.

Ex : first loop

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="http://apte.local/images/favicon.ico">
            <title>title</title>            
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="http://apte.local/images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">
<link href="http://apte.local/css/style.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://apte.local/js/jquery/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- Scripts -->
```

second loop :

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="http://apte.local/images/favicon.ico">
            <title>title - title</title><!-- title generated with headTitle -->            
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- in layout headMeta is used to generate meta -->
    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="http://apte.local/images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon">
<link href="http://apte.local/css/style.min.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://apte.local/js/jquery/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://apte.local/images/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"> <!-- in layout headLink helper is used to generate the link -->
    <!-- Scripts -->
```

I don't know if my idea is right, I thought that using the same logic as unit testing an action could do the job, am I missing something ?

I wonder if there is a way to trigger the events I already coded and that are working fine in http mode.

(I've tested to wire an echo 'test' on EVENT_DISPATCH but my event is fired only once, the $controller->dispatch(...) doesn't fire the dispatch event of the current event manager.)

If someone has an idea, or has faced a similar case, I would be glad to read how you've done to solve that.

Comment: What does the third loop do? Can you share the template code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found out how to resolve this issue, in fact it came from plugin headMeta, headTitle, these plugin use cache to store all entry added (append, prepend or set). When instanciating a new renderer or get the current, the cache is not resetted and of course, when rendering the second time, more entries are added to the current plugin cache...
So after each render, the cache must be cleared to avoid the multiple title, meta, etc...

My code to fix that
In ConsoleController::buildStaticCacheAction()

```
// Following code is in a loop
// Dispatch to get the ViewModel
$view = $this->forward()->dispatch('Application\Controller\Index', array("controller" => "index", "action" => "showad", "ad_id" => $current['adId']));
// Getting renderer
$renderer = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewManager')->getRenderer();
// Render
$html = $renderer->render($view);
//Clear head plugins cache
$renderer->headTitle()->setContainer(new Container());
$renderer->headMeta()->setContainer(new Container());
$renderer->headLink()->setContainer(new Container());
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing it the $view->setTemplate('showad') is messing it somehow. Once you get the Response from the dispatch, you can set it as a nested ViewModel or just as a variable to your new ViewModel() right?

Regarding generating the requests, instead of bootstrapping like Unit testing, you can generate [console requests and create console aware controllers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.console.introduction.html).